# Facebook external login setup in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core-6.0

**Message:** You've successfully authenticated with Facebook. Click the Register button to finish logging in.

but the email not showing.

I follow the instructions from here.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/facebook-logins?view=aspnetcore-6.0

But it doesn't work. How can I solve it?

Comment: what does `but the email not showing.` mean?

Comment: Xinran Shen please view
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14i4vMGAyM9DxlAhLpaSl2QQLSCSK4Eyj?usp=share_link

 if (info.Principal.HasClaim(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Email))
 
**email not found**

Answer (score 0):

1. Please login facebook and find the personal settings, make sure this account has binded the email information.
2. Check the facebook app's status, [it must be reviewed by Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/permissions/) can check more details.